# Appearance of double border in dropdown menu in horizontal navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a simple horizontal navigation bar using `html`, `css` and `javascript`. The navigation bar contains a dropdown menu (named More). Clicking on the More menu causes hidden links to be shown (vertically) beneath the More heading, and clicking again causes the links to be hidden again.

In the css file, I have set all of the links in the navigation bar to have a double border. However, the appearance of the borders around the links in the dropdown menu look different to the appearance of the borders around the other links. Specifically, the borders at the top and bottom of the links in the dropdown menu look different to the borders of the other links. Why is this?

I've included the `html`, `css` and `javascript` code.

Thanks,
Mfl

[image: Screenshot]

```js
function clickMoreMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hiddenlinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#navbar { 
    padding : 0; 
    display : flex;   
    width : 400px; 
    margin-left : auto;  
    margin-right : auto; 
    margin-bottom : 20px; 
} 

.navoption {
   text-align : center; 
   width: 100px; 
   display : inline-block; 
   float : left; 
}  

#moremenu {
    display : inline-block; 
}


#hiddenlinks {
    display: none;
    position : absolute; 
    z-index : 1;
}


#navbar a { 
    display : block; 
    text-align : center; 
    text-decoration : none; 
    padding-top : 10px;  
    padding-bottom : 10px; 
    width : 100px; 
    color : Blue; 
    background : Yellow; 
    border-style : double; 
    border-color : Blue;  
    border-width : medium; 
} 


#navbar a.currentpage { 
    color : DarkBlue; 
    background : Gold; 
} 

#navbar a:hover { 
    background : Blue; 
    color : Yellow; 
} 

h1 { 
    color : blue; 
    text-align : center; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Border Test</title>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Border Test</h1>
<nav id = "navbar">
    <div class="navoption">
        <a href="index.html" class="currentpage">Index</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navoption">
        <a href="option2.html">Option 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navoption">
        <a href="option3.html">Option 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navoption" id="moremenu">
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clickMoreMenu()">More...</a>
        </div>
        <div id="hiddenlinks">
            <a href="option4.html">Option 4</a>
            <a href="option5.html">Option 5</a>
            <a href="option6.html">Option 6</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="moremenu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its because you added `border: double` and the other elements are on a next line and not colliding with each other.

Comment: Are you confused by these boundaries? - https://ibb.co/f0xCWDs

Comment: Just add it to your css. - `#hiddenlinks a { border-top-style: hidden;}`

Comment: @tacoshy are the elements of the class .navoption (Index, Option 2 and Option 3 and More) colliding with each other on the left and right? If so can you recommend a way to stop them from colliding? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because border is 1 px thick and when 2 borders are next to each other it will look like there is just one border that is 2 px thick. You could add negative top margin of -1 px on "#hiddenlinks a" to fix it.

```js
function clickMoreMenu() {
  var x = document.getElementById("hiddenlinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#navbar { 
    padding : 0; 
    display : flex;   
    width : 400px; 
    margin-left : auto;  
    margin-right : auto; 
    margin-bottom : 20px; 
} 

.navoption {
   text-align : center; 
   width: 100px; 
   display : inline-block; 
   float : left; 
}  

#moremenu {
    display : inline-block; 
}


#hiddenlinks {
    display: none;
    position : absolute; 
    z-index : 1;
}

#hiddenlinks a {
  margin-top: -1px;
}

#navbar a { 
    display : block; 
    text-align : center; 
    text-decoration : none; 
    padding-top : 10px;  
    padding-bottom : 10px; 
    width : 100px; 
    color : Blue; 
    background : Yellow; 
    border-style : double; 
    border-color : Blue;  
    border-width : medium; 
} 


#navbar a.currentpage { 
    color : DarkBlue; 
    background : Gold; 
} 

#navbar a:hover { 
    background : Blue; 
    color : Yellow; 
} 

h1 { 
    color : blue; 
    text-align : center; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Border Test</title>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Border Test</h1>
<nav id = "navbar">
    <div class="navoption">
        <a href="index.html" class="currentpage">Index</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navoption">
        <a href="option2.html">Option 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navoption">
        <a href="option3.html">Option 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navoption" id="moremenu">
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clickMoreMenu()">More...</a>
        </div>
        <div id="hiddenlinks">
            <a href="option4.html">Option 4</a>
            <a href="option5.html">Option 5</a>
            <a href="option6.html">Option 6</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="moremenu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggested solutions. I found a different solution. Each element of the class `navoption`, which contains a link, had its width set to 100px. However, the links themselves also had their width set to 100px. The additional width of the borders caused the width of the links to be above 100px, so each `navoption` element had insufficient space to show all of its contained link on the left and right. I commented out the width for the `navoption` class, leaving just the width of the links themselves, and the borders on the left and right of the links now appear consistent with the borders on the top and bottom.